# Lock Kibana Dashboard

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have set up Elastic Search and Kibana and prepared different monitoring dashboard. So how can i lock my dashboard so dashboard is visible to all and even they can apply filters and visualize but it shouldn't change original dashboard so when they open dashboard again it should be same as one which i had prepared. I tried to check elastic search website and they offer subscription for X-pack which provides role based access control. But is there anyway I can lock the dashboard rather than subscription because i used Kibana as it was open source. 
Thank You in advance.
- Sam

Comment: This is a very specific problem related to ElasticSearch & Kibana products. It's not really a programmation or development issue so you should consider asking this question on Elastic Forum : https://discuss.elastic.co/

Comment: Sure, Mickael thank you for your advise. I already did that but as i wanted to get advise and suggestions on development/programming approach i should follow to accomplish this.